How do address MathJax down with RShiny
I woke up this morning to a new issue where previously working code with Mathjax was working, but now it is not. It appears the issue is broad. I reproduced it on several machines, which is also an issue on the server where I run the apps (which has not been touched). Is there any way to address this?


I'm posting the answer here in case anyone is searching today. You can simply load the most recent version of Mathjax directly from the source.
You can add
tagList(
    tags$script(
      src = "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
    )
  # ... Rest of App
)
                   


The cdn.mathjax.org site was decommissioned in 2017 (see your browser console for a message indicating that), so you are not actually getting the latest version, only the latest as of that time.  That would be v2.7.1, which is quite old.  The current version is 3.2.2, and the highest v2 is 2.7.9.
